# Method getInfo() not found?

Tags: java

The problem comes in the toString method of the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LinkedDeque<T> // implements  Deque<T> 
{
private Node head;  
private Node tail; 

private int size;

private class Node // Node class
{
    T info;
    Node next; 
    Node prev; 

    private Node (T info, Node prev, Node next)
    {
        this.info = info;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }

    private T getInfo()
    {
        return this.info;
    }

    private Node getNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }

    private Node getPrev()
    {
        return this.prev;
    }
}

public LinkedDeque ()
{
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.size = 0;
}

public static void main()
{

}

public int size ()
{
    Node count = head;
    while(count.getNext() != null)
    {
        size++;
        count = count.getNext();
    }
    return size;
}

public String toString()
{   
    return this.getInfo();
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return size() == 0;
}
```

}

My compiler keeps giving me an error saying that the getInfo method is missing. Any help would be appreciated! Initially, I thought this was due to the fact that the Node class was private, but the Node getNext() method works fine in the method size().

Comment: In `size()`, you are calling `count.getNext()`. In `toString()`, you call `this.getInfo()`. What is the difference between `count` and `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toString` method is a member of `LinkedDeque` not `Node`.  `LinkedDeque` does not have a `getInfo` method.

Not sure what it is you were trying to achieve, but you may consider moving that method into the `Node` class...